# Confusing use of 'for'

Tags: prepositions

Some dictionaries use this perculiar construction '**of or for**' to define certain words, mostly adjectives. Here's a few examples from the Cambridge dictionary:

- *wholesale*: **of or for** the selling of goods in large amounts at low prices
- *start-up*: **of or for** a new business venture
- *primary*: **of or for** the teaching of young children

I'm okay with the use of '**of**' (supposedly in the sense of 'relating to'), but I fail to parse the '**for**' in any of these. What exactly is its role here? Maybe it makes use of some obscure meaning of '**for**' I'm not familiar with? Maybe some words are ommited for brevity, like '**used for**' or '**for descriptions of**'? The phrase "*... for the selling of goods in large amounts*" as is just doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the word "primary" can mean "for the teaching of young children"

For example, you can talk about "A primary school".  This is a school for the teaching of young children. This is not an obscure sense of "for", it is the standard meaning which indicates the *purpose* of the school.

Similarly, you might describe the purpose of a "wholesale store" as "a store for the selling of goods in large amounts but at low prices."

The preposition "of" indicates a more general "related" sense

Comment: I haven't looked at it at quite this angle for some reason. Thanks!